# Does spark perform transformations row by row or together?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand spark and have the following code where `df,df2,df3,df4 are Dataset<Row>`

```
df=df.join(df2,"ID");
df4=df4.join(df3,"ID");
df=df.union(df4);
long count=df.count();
```

My question is how do the transformation happen?  In the above example, does the union waits for both joins to complete **fully** (i.e join for all rows is done) and then start the union? Or does it goes row by row in a pipelined way, where once join for one row is complete, the union transform starts on it (even though join for other rows is still going on)?

I tried searching on this but am not able to find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explain()` to see what happen.

```
df.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- *(5) Project [ID#3599L, VALUE#3600, VALUE#3604]
:  +- *(5) SortMergeJoin [ID#3599L], [ID#3603L], Inner
:     :- *(2) Sort [ID#3599L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(ID#3599L, 200), true, [id=#1332]
:     :     +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(ID#3599L)
:     :        +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#3599L,VALUE#3600]
:     +- *(4) Sort [ID#3603L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [ID#3603L, VALUE#3604], Exchange hashpartitioning(ID#3599L, 200), true, [id=#1332]
+- *(10) Project [ID#3599L, VALUE#3600, VALUE#3609]
   +- *(10) SortMergeJoin [ID#3599L], [ID#3608L], Inner
      :- *(7) Sort [ID#3599L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- ReusedExchange [ID#3599L, VALUE#3600], Exchange hashpartitioning(ID#3599L, 200), true, [id=#1332]
      +- *(9) Sort [ID#3608L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- ReusedExchange [ID#3608L, VALUE#3609], Exchange hashpartitioning(ID#3599L, 200), true, [id=#1332]
```

Sort, SortMergeJoin, Project, and Union. This happens when you take an action, such as `count()` and before that, spark will just plan how to proceed.

Comment: I understand this but my question is something else. I want to understand how the transformations happen:- row by row, partition by partition, or all at once.